# could not find file: hibernate.cgf.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I read many posts, but no one suits my issue.
I put  hibernate.cgf.xml under the "src" folder of eclipse, according to what I learnt by  reading some example on the internet.

But when I run my application, I stil get the error `"could not find file: hibernate.cgf.xml"`

This is my web application

[image]

this is the class the start the application

```
public class TestHibernateInsert {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        //Add new Employee object
        EmployeeEntity emp = new EmployeeEntity();
        emp.setEmail("lokesh@mail.com");
        emp.setNome("Nome");
        emp.setCognome("Cognome");
        emp.setPassword("Password");

        //Save the employee in database
        session.save(emp);

        //Commit the transaction
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        HibernateUtil.shutdown();
    }
}
```

this is the SessionFactory  class

```
   public class HibernateUtil
    {
        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

        private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(new File("hibernate.cgf.xml")).buildSessionFactory();
            }
            catch (Throwable ex) {
                // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        public static void shutdown() {
            // Close caches and connection pools
            getSessionFactory().close();
        }
    }
```

this is the persistent object class

```
Entity
@Table(name = "utente")
public class EmployeeEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154676L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "nome", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "cognome", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String cognome;

    @Column(name = "password", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String password;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    //Getters and setters

}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have developed a web application using eclipse. By default hibernate looks for the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in root of classpath.

So finally the file should be placed in `WEB-INF/classes` directory which is the root of classpath of a web-application.

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali, can you edit your question and show where the file is placed?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time.I put the xml file under WEB-INF/classes and now it works. I already tried it without solving the problem, probably it was a problem of eclipse. I cleaned my project, restarted eclipse and now it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please rename your file from `hibernate.cgf.xml` to `hibernate.cfg.xml`

And change your `buildSessionFactory()` method in HibernateUtil class

```
        private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            }
            catch (Throwable ex) {
                // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your existing config file to hibernate.cfg.xml

or use below code to create your session

Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
   cfg.configure("hibernate.cgf.xml");